# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with type error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

When I run node server.js in nodejs, the error message shows 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. I have installed all relevant libraries (e.g. request) and have looked at different relevant posts. However, the issue still persists.
I think it has something to do with either the express or the index file.
any recommendations?
Many thanks!

```
(node:14320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at pathtoRegexp (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:63:49)
at new Layer (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:45:17)
at Function.use (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:464:17)
at Function.<anonymous> (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Function.use (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
at _default (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/src/loaders/express.js:28:9)
at _callee$ (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/src/loaders/index.js:8:11)
at tryCatch (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/floyd/Desktop/icigai/marketplace_backend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)

(node:14320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Edit:

```js
// express.js

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import multer from 'multer';

// API routes
import * as routes from '../api';

// const app = express(); // for itelisense only..

export default ({ app }) => {
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    /**
     * Enable cors on all actions
     */
    app.use(cors());

    /**
     * Transform string to JSON.
     */
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).any());
    /**
     * SERVERS
     */
        
    app.use(process.env.ROUTING_PREFIX, routes.default);

    /**
     * Check API health.
     */
    app.get(`${process.env.ROUTING_PREFIX}status`, (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('SEQT IS UP AND RUNNING!');
    });

    /**
     * Catch 404 and forward to error handle.
     */
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    /**
     * Global error catcher.
     */
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({
            errors: {
                message: err.message,
            },
        });
    });
};
```

```js
// index.js

import expressLoader from './express';
import logger from './logger';

export default async ({ app }) => {
    /**
     * loads express essentials
    */
    await expressLoader({ app });
    logger.log('info', 'Express Loader has initialized successfully! ✅');
};
```

```js
// server.js

// This is the one responsible for the Route Alias
import express from 'express';
import 'dotenv/config.js';

// This is used for logging
import logger from './loaders/logger';

require('module-alias/register');

const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, `../.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`) });

// This is the DB Sequelize instance
const sequelize = require('./sequelize');

// We are creating a function to use the Async & Await syntax
async function startServer() {
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;

    app.use(express.static('./'));
    // Testing the DB Connections
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        logger.info('Connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }

    // Import the express loaders (Packages)
    await require('./loaders').default({ app });

    app.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            process.exit(1);
        }
        logger.info(`
        ################################################
              Server listening on port: ${port}  
        ################################################`);
    });
}

startServer();
```

Comment: Upd you question and show your code

Comment: I hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an `undefined` or `null` value to `app.use` will result in the shown error. So I'm guessing something is wrong with your env-variable as you're using e.g.:

```
app.use(process.env.ROUTING_PREFIX, routes.default);
```

Try to do a `console.log(process.env.ROUTING_PREFIX)` and check if the value is set or it's `undefined`.